# IntelliSense flagging errors on <limits.h> values

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Getting used to a new IDE, and I'm getting some odd behavior. It's flagging errors on the SHRT_MAX and USHRT_MAX used below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void){

      printf("The value of SHRT_MAX is: %d\n", SHRT_MAX);
      printf("The vakue of USHRT_MAX is: %d\n", USHRT_MAX);

      return 0;
}
```

The tooltip over the error states: "Error SHRT_MAX not defined".

However, the program compiles and runs as expected, flagging two new errors during build:

```
3   IntelliSense: identifier "SHRT_MAX" is undefined    
4   IntelliSense: identifier "USHRT_MAX" is undefined
```

Any insight on this?

Comment: Complain at the vendor. This is no error.

Comment: Ignore IntelliSense errors for C code and just fix the diagnostics reported by the compiler. Visual Studio is mainly a C++ IDE but I think VS2015 improved IntelliSense for C. Do you have to use VS2012?

Comment: @cremno This may be what I need to convince me to update. Thanks. I assumed they were ignorable non-errors, I was just hoping there was some fix for 2012.

Comment: Also, if either of you want to quickly format those into an answer, I'll happily upvote, accept and we can close the question.